# Is something wrong with my query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I'm working on a database with 3 tables, some with overlapping information. A few columns from each table can be updated by the user via the web app that I am creating. But... There is an issue. Not sure what it is, but my updates aren't happening. I am wondering if something is wrong with my query. (Actually, after debugging, I am quite certain there is).

```
    if (empty($errors)) {   
    $query1 = "UPDATE owner SET
            name = '{$name}'
        WHERE ownerId= '{$ownerId}'";
    $query1_result = mysql_query($query1);
    if (mysql_affected_rows()==1) { 
        $query2 = "UPDATE queue_acl SET
                    date_expires = '{$date_expires}' 
                WHERE user_id='{$ownerId}'";
        $query2_result = mysql_query($query2);
        if (mysql_affected_rows()==2) {
            $query3 = "UPDATE ownerOrganization SET
                    orgId = {$orgId}
                WHERE ownerId = '{$ownerId}'";
            $query3_result = mysql_query($query3);
            if (mysql_affected_rows()==3) {
                    $_SESSION['name'] = $name;
                    $_SESSION['updates_occurred'] = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Sorry if it is trivial; I have never worked with multiple tables before.

Comment: You might want to look into mysql_error(). It's usually much easier letting the database tell you what's wrong with your query than combing through it yourself.

Comment: @NVidodiv why you have '{$date_expires}' instead '$date_expires'?

Comment: Hi, I put the mysql_error at the very bottom (or should I put it after every mysql_affected_rows?). It doesn't show any error... In fact, it *looks* like it works on the web app. But, when you check the database nothing has actually been updated

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient MySQL extension: it is no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should use either the improved [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) extension or the [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) abstraction layer.

Comment: If possible, you might want to try echoing/logging everything to see where the breakdown is. There's quite a lot there where it could be going wrong.

Comment: Why do you check for `mysql_affected_rows()==1` ...`==2` ...`==3`? Are there two and three affected rows in these two tables? Or just one for each user as in the first? The number of affected rows may always be one if your `ownerId` and `user_id` are (unique) primary keys of the tables.

Comment: @aynber That is what I had initially tried; a print or echo after each mysql_error, and other places in the code. It did very little to help. I took it out because I thought it would distract from the code

Comment: after each mysql_affected_rows, I meant

Comment: @mixable I had them each as ==1, but because a row in each table needs to be updated, I though it made more sense this way

Comment: Ok, but this may cause the problem. `mysql_affected_rows()` only returns the number of affected rows for the _last_ query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a good habit to update tables the way you do it. If the updates are relating somehow you might want to think about creating a transaction. Transactions make sure that all updates are executed (and if not, a rollback is done (which means no update will be executed)):

```
// disable autocommit 
mysqli_autocommit($dblink, FALSE);

// queries
$query1 = mysqli_query($dblink, "UPDATE owner SET name = '{$name}' WHERE ownerId= {$ownerId}'");
$query2 = mysqli_query($dblink, "UPDATE queue_acl SET date_expires = '{$date_expires}' WHERE user_id='{$ownerId}'");
$query3 = mysqli_query($dblink, "UPDATE ownerOrganization SET orgId = {$orgId} WHERE ownerId = '{$ownerId}'");

if($query1 && $query2 && $query3)
{
   mysqli_commit($dblink);
   $_SESSION['name'] = $name;
   $_SESSION['updates_occurred'] = true;
}
else
   mysqli_rollback($dblink);
```

I haven't tested it but it guess it should work. Also you should take a look at mysqli or prepared statements since mysql_ is deprecated.

Comment: Hi libjup, thank you for the great answer :-). However, I get dozens of error messages when I execute this. Mostly repeat messages of "$dblink not defined", "mysqli_autocommit() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given", and "mysqli_query expects query to be the first argument", etc. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Hi Vidovic,

just initialize $dblink as the following:

$dblink = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "dbname") or die("Login-Error");

Comment: I actually had tried that initially, but I get this error -- mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given. (This is when I choose the database I wish to connect to). The code looks like: $db_select = mysqli_select_db(DB_NAME,$dblink);

Comment: Nevermind, fixed that... still no response from my db when updates are made though. Agh this is frustrating

Comment: just saw that I wrote "dbaselink" in the commit function. that should be dblink of course and what do you mean with "response from my database"? are the updates commited?

Comment: I mean that the database isn't being updated with the new values (is that what you mean by updates commited?)

Answer (score 0):

The first issue might be scope related. Your if conditionals are wrong?

```
If (result ==1)
{
  if(result == 2)
  { 
   ...
  }
}
```

Thus if your first result is more than 1 then all the internal conditionals will be skipped.

If I understand it should be:

```
if(result ==1)
{
}
elseif(result ==2)
{
}
...(other conditions)...
else
{ 
}
```

I would recommend a base case to catch if you have more results than you expect.

The second issue might be that you quote around all data except orgId = {$orgId}. This should probably be orgId = '{$orgId}' if the id is some random string then not quoting will cause issues.

One last concern is to check ownerId. If that is blank for some reason then your query will fail because where id=0 (assuming you have auto increment on) will never be true. Put a if(!empty(ownerId) conditional.

Comment: Hi Shawn, thanks! I am not sure if I want "if..else" statements because I need *all* the updates to execute. That is why I set it up that way - if one fails, all should fail. I took your suggestion regarding 'orgId'. Ownerid is not autoincremented but it is unique (it's actually a username; eg mine would be nvidovic). So it should never be 0, or any integer at that

Comment: But if the variable containing the username is blank, then your where clause will become WHERE ownerId='', which would be an empty set. Also you could probably do all the updates with JOINS.